# Downloading Json data from website

Tags: python, json

I am trying to write a python script which will take a bunch of urls one at a time and fetch the response content of that url and store it as json files.

Here is what I wrote initially to get the response of the url

```
def download_json()

    params={'id':00163E0BD0C1FA89,
            'list':'141',
            'queue': 'gen',
            'type': 'abc_stat'
           }



    req_obj= requests.get(link, params=params)
    print(req_obj.url)
    print(req_obj.status_code)

    return req_obj
```

It creates the right url as when I copy the url directly in browser it shows me the output in json format. Here is one row of json output i am seeing on the browser:

```
{
  "DATA" : [
    {
      "SCHEMA" : "abc_4_QAATu2.",
      "ID" : "QAATu2",
      "IM_ID" : "22faba86_c9e0_4dbc",
      "S_NUMBER" : "502379284",
      "CONFIG_TYPE" : "las_home_type",
      "CONFIG_KEY" : "las_home_key",
      "CONFIG_LONG_V" : "1",
      "CONFIG_STRING_V" : "https://abc-deg/development",
      "MODIFIED_DATE" : "Unknown"
    },
```

So this does show that data is returned in json format when I enter the url in browser directly.

However my requests object has this for headers:

Out[26]:

```
{'content-length': '15457', 'expires': '0', 'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, private', 'set-cookie': 'login-XSRF_RZA=2018051-axJnifQUpOnrS8WCFI; path=/abc/deo/cpo; secure; HttpOnly, usercontext=client=002; path=/', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'pragma': 'no-cache, no-store, private'}
```

Now when I do requests.json() to get the data in json python object I get the following error

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-4cfc1a694fcf> in <module>()
----> 1 req_obj.json()

/Users/anaconda/envs/dl/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
    890                     # used.
    891                     pass
--> 892         return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
    893 
    894     @property

/Users/anaconda/envs/dl/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    317             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    318             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 319         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    320     if cls is None:
    321         cls = JSONDecoder

/Users/anaconda/envs/dl/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    337 
    338         """
--> 339         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    340         end = _w(s, end).end()
    341         if end != len(s):

/Users/anaconda/envs/dl/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    356         except StopIteration as err:
--> 357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    358         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 2)
```

**EDIT:**

The content_type if you see in above headers is shown as html even when on browser it shows json as output

However when I do

```
req_obj.json 

<bound method Response.json of <Response [200]>>
```

But req_obj.json() gives below error.

Any idea why it is not able to convert the data into json format when output is actually in json format as shown above? Thanks

Comment: What happens if you use `req_obj.text` instead of `req_obj.json()`? What does it output?

Comment: I get the html output. I am not sure why it is giving me html output when on the browser I get json output as shown. In the headers content_type is though mentioned as html. How can I change that?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content):

> In case the JSON decoding fails, `r.json()` raises an exception. For
>   example, if the response gets a 204 (No Content), or if the response
>   contains invalid JSON, attempting `r.json()` raises `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded.`

Although it's not throwing the same error message, the cause appears to be the same: you're probably not getting JSON as an answer, which would explain why it `JSONDecode` throws an exception.

You should be able to confirm this by printing `req_obj.text` instead of using `req_obj.json()`.

As for how to fix it, I suspect that there must be something different between the request you're making using the browser and the one you're making using Python (such as different parameters).

I suggest you read [this](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) to further investigate the source of the problem.

Comment: req_obj.text gives me the whole html source code. So it is working. 

Also when i do req_obj.json and not req_obj.json() it does print 

<bound method Response.json of <Response [200]>>

Comment: The request I am making to browser uses the same url which I created using the python script. Look at the print(url) in my code that prints the url and I use that url to paste in browser. So its the same url with same parameters

Comment: It's not working if you're seeing HTML instead of json. That's why `req_obj.json()` is throwing an exception, the request is returning HTML rather than the JSON you're expecting.

Comment: And that is what I am not able to understand. Why will it throw json in browser then? The output I pasted in my question is the json output. Both are same link

Comment: There has to be something different between the request you're making on the browser and the one you're making using Python. Have you tried directly using the full url with the parameters in it? e.g. `req_obj = requests.get('your/site/url?id=00163E0BD0C1FA89&list=141&queue=gen&type=abc_stat');`

Comment: If you look in the code, req_obj.url prints out the full url. It is coming out of get method. I am using this printed url and putting that in browser to get the json output in browser. So there is no chance of having different url

Answer (score -1):

According to this document: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

You could check the `req_obj.status_code` and `r.headers['content-type']`. If the status_code is 200 and the content type is `'application/json; charset=utf8'` then you can try to check for `req_obj.json()`.

Comment: Status_code is 200. However content_type is html. I don't know why. On browser it throws the output in json as I pasted above. 

Also when I do req_obj.json (without parentheses) it does give me 200 code. 

<bound method Response.json of <Response [200]>>. Check edit pls

Comment: there are a few website that return json if the header accept is json. 
You can try:

`requests.get(url, headers={'accept': 'application/json'})`